# Multidimensional Object to array in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, object

I want to send datas to *ngFor. I get the Data from the LocalStorage as a JSON Object. After I parse the object, I dont understand how I can make the full Object to an array? This is the Object:

```
{
  "Monti": {
    "name": "Visa & MasterCard",
    "code": "monti",
    "deposit": "Free",
    "depositProcessing": "Instant",
    "icon": "<img src=\"//cdn.example.com/_payicons/monti.png\"/>",
    "supportWithdrawal": true,
    "withdrawAllowedWithoutDeposit": false,
    "depositLimits": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "min": 10,
      "max": 5000
    }
  },
  "Montii": {
    "name": "Visa & MasterCard",
    "code": "monti",
    "deposit": "Free",
    "depositProcessing": "Instant",
    "icon": "<img src=\"//cdn.example.com/_payicons/monti.png\"/>",
    "supportWithdrawal": true,
    "withdrawAllowedWithoutDeposit": false,
    "depositLimits": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "min": 10,
      "max": 5000
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object which contains two other objects. I think what you wanted to have is an array of those objects which would like something like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Visa & MasterCard",
        "code": "monti",
        "deposit": "Free",
        "depositProcessing": "Instant",
        "icon": "",
        "supportWithdrawal": true,
        "withdrawAllowedWithoutDeposit": false,
        "depositLimits": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "min": 10,
            "max": 5000
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Visa & MasterCard",
        "code": "monti",
        "deposit": "Free",
        "depositProcessing": "Instant",
        "icon": "",
        "supportWithdrawal": true,
        "withdrawAllowedWithoutDeposit": false,
        "depositLimits": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "min": 10,
            "max": 5000
        }
    }
]
```

You just have to fix it at the moment when you save it to the `localStorage`. If it's not possible you can run a 'for in' loop on that object to make an array out of it.

```
let arr = [];
for(let key in obj) {
  arr.push(obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that works. But one question, why I dont use the Obj[value]?

Comment: Because you get some value by object's key, not by the value itself.